# F#, assignment operator vs set operator

Tags: f#

I have started with F# and some code structure wonder me. For example:

I have next code:

```
let mutable s = 10
s <- 1 + s
printf "%i" s
```

Everything is clear from math side. I marked "s" as mutable and assigned the new value to "s". Result is 11.

Let me try other part of code:

```
let mutable s = 10
s = 1 + s
printf "%i" s
```

This code was worked. But I see that `s = 1 + s` is a bit strange from the math side. Result of executing of this was 10.

My question, what go on in the last sample? Why didn't I get a error? Is `s = 1 + s` just ignored? Why? I didn't get any error in the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your second question -

> Why didn't I get a error? Is s = 1 + s just ignored? Why? I didn't get any error in the output.

The reason for this is that F# distinguishes between top-level scope in a script file and local scope. When you are in a script file (`*.fsx` file in Visual Studio or inside Try F#), then you probably want to write a sequence of expressions (that may return a value) and execute them interactively one by one. This means that when you write `s = 1 + s` on one line, this is not an error because you can evaluate the line (select it and hit Ctrl+Enter or Alt+Enter) and see the result in the interactive output.

However, when this appears inside a function (or in other *local scope* where you are not expected to evaluate it interactively), you get a warning. The easiest way to see is to create a local scope using `do` (and this works in Try F# too):

```
do
  let mutable s = 10
  s = 1 + s           // Warning: This expression should have type 'unit', 
                      //    but has type 'bool'. If assigning to a property 
                      //    use the syntax 'obj.Prop <- expr'.
  printf "%i" s
```

Answer (score 5):

The code

```
s=1+s
```

will does not modify `s` - the equivalent C# is

```
s==1+s
```

which just returns `false`

In fact, the compiler should have issued a warning on that line about a value being unused.

The `=` operator just does an equality check - it does **not** assign any values.

Comment: You are right. My mistake was that I tried to out the result in the next way "printf "%b" s = 1 + s". And it is crashed. When I modified my code in the next manner "printf "%b" (s = 1 + s)". It works correct and return "false" (as expected)

Comment: Moreover, I am using http://www.tryfsharp.org - so it is possible that I have limited output.

Comment: @RredCat I don't get any warning in `fsi` either - they only appear when using the full compiler